# Finding optimal path for a reproduction problem

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms, path

Given a finite set of lists with elements ($e_1, e_2,..., e_7$) and $e_i = True, False$.
It is possible to create a new list by taking two lists and apply the $\land$ operator on both lists ($e_i$ in the new list is $True$ only if  $e_i$ are $True$ in both parent lists)

The aim is to find a way to obtain the list with all elements equal to $True$.

One can easily find that by applying this operator there are no ways to produce a new list that is closer to the final result since $\land$ cannot transform $False$ into $True$. This operator is then modified to be $\land^*((a, b), (c, d))$, which FORCE $e_a$, $e_b$ in the first list and $e_c$, $e_d$ in the second list to be passed to the new list. Not all values for the tuples are allowed, one can choose between:

$$(1, None) ... (7, None), (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)$$

Each time we apply an operator it has an associated cost depending on the tuple used, C((x, None)) = 1000, C((x, y)) = 5000

Few examples:

$$[T, F, F, F, F, F, F] \land^*((1, None), (2, None)) [F, T, F, F, F, F, F] = [T, T, F, F, F, F, F]$$
$$[T, T, F, F, F, F, F] \land^*((1, 2), (7, None)) [F, F, F, F, F, F, T] = [T, T, F, F, F, F, T]$$
$$[T, T, F, F, F, F, T] \land^*((1, 2), (3, 4)) [F, F, T, T, T, F, T] = [T, T, T, T, F, F, T]$$

Cost = 2000, 6000, 10000

Each time a new list is produced it is added to the initial set and can be used like any others.

An additional condition is that lists can reproduce only a limited of time, which is equal to $R = 8 - N_{True}$ for initial lists and is equal to $R = min(R_1, R_2) - 1$ for new lists created with parents 1 and 2.

Depending on the initial set of lists, there might be multiple ways to obtain the result. I am looking mainly for the two paths where $min(C)$, $max(R_{final})$

I've never coded something like that, so far I tried to use the only algorithm I have experience with: basin hopping. It is not working so well, it is either giving always the same good answer or not finding the final list at all.

Is there a specific kind of algorithms for this kind of problem?

Comment: I don't think I understand you. Do you want to do the "and" operator ($\land$) between lists until you reach a list of all "True"s? The "and" operator can only transform "True" into "False", and **not** vice versa.

Comment: That's why "items" are introduced. Example if the parent 1 hold an item allowing to pass the second element and the parent 2 the fourth: $[T, T, F, F, T, F, T] \land [T, F, F, T, F, F, T] = [T, T, F, T, F, F, T]$ allowing you to "improve" the new list.

Comment: Your calculation is incorrect. The result of this $\land$ is $[T,F,F,F,F,F,T]$, which is clearly worse than both parents. You simply cannot get more "True" than what you currently have, and thus there is no point in doing the $\land$ operations

Comment: @nirshahar I agree with you, this should be the result without parents holding any items. I am sorry that this is unclear, I should state this as a modified operator $\land^*(a,b)$ which means that $e_a$ in the first list and $e_b$ in the second list will be given to the new list no matter what, in this case $[T,T,F,F,T,F,T] \land^*(2,4) [T,F,F,T,F,F,T] = [T,T,F,T,F,F,T]$

Comment: So basically this is an $\land$ but on $(a,b)$ it acts as an $\lor$ instead?

Comment: @nirshahar Yes, exactly

Comment: Then please edit this into your question.

Comment: @nirshahar I edited the question, thank you for your advice.